# How do I associate an Event with a method Load?

Tags: c#, events, delegates, event-listener, observers

I want to register every time the method Load is used. To do this, I want to use a Event, like if it's called I want to increment a variable.

This Load is a method that gets data from a database, the point is to know the number of accesses made.

Can some one help me understand how to create such an Event.

*Method definition:*

```
protected override V Load(DbDataReader dr)
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/event-pattern

Comment: I would use an [attribute](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_attributes.htm) instead of an event. Does not sound like an event to me.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to make an event, for a single purpose which you already know - counting the number of times a database is accessed. You *can* implement it this way:

```
public class Foo : TheClassThatDefinesLoad
{
    public event EventHandler Loaded;

    protected override V Load(DbDataReader dr)
    {
        var result = base.Load(dr);

        // An event handler with no listeners is null by default
        if (Loaded != null)
            Loaded.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());

        return result;
    }
}

// Somewhere in the calling code:
int loads = 0;
var foo = new Foo();
foo.Loaded += (sender, args) => loads += 1;
```

This is not thread safe, but it is a basic example of how to achieve what you want. However, if the library that you are using already provides a virtual method that you can override, do you need to create an event as well? You can easily achieve the same thing without an event:

```
public class Foo : TheClassThatDefinesLoad
{
    public int TotalLoads { get; private set; }

    protected override V Load(DbDataReader dr)
    {
        var result = base.Load(dr);
        TotalLoads += 1;
        return result;
    }
}
```

In this case, I do think an event is appropriate here (I also think `TheClassThatDefinesLoad` should be the one to define the event), but keep in mind that you don't always need to use events.